# Zurb Foundation for Apps for websites?

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

The new Zurb "Foundation for Apps" seems great. However, all the sample layouts given are for "desktop-like Web apps."

Is it possible to use Foundation for Apps for very dynamic Web sites using AngularJS?

Is it possible use all of the resources from Foundation 5?

Like widgets? building blocks? icon fonts?

Is "Foundation for Apps" something like "Foundation for Sites using AngularJS instead of JQuery" or more like a new Ember.js competitor?

Thanks,
Ashley.

Comment: This is a technical question, i.e. Is it possible ...?  Please open it again, I am looking for a clear yes or not answer and I think the info will be valuable to others.  Please read the question closely before putting on hold as off-topic.  Thanks, Ashley.

Comment: You should considering posting this on [the foundation forum](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum) where it would be more appropriate.